# How to recall publish method in meteor

Tags: mysql, meteor

After retrieve data from database using meteor-mysql,if data update in database, retrieve data from publish could not update

here is my publish method:

```
Meteor.publish('sites',function() { 
   db.select(this, { query:'select * from Site', 
   }); 
 }); 

and sites = new MysqlSubscription("sites");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need its the `changed()` method.

> changed() is automatically called when the query updates and is most
>   likely to only be called manually from a method stub on the client.

from [package doc](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql)

```
client or server
myDatabse = new MysqlSubscription('myPublishName');
```

and you will get the updates using this.

```
myDatabse.addEventListener('update', function(index, record){
  console.log(record.fields.someField);
});
```

**Update**

Senha be sure to read [this tutorial](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql/blob/master/getting_started.md), just to make sure you have the correct code.

Comment: yes, i m using numtel:mysql. I used changed method as mysubscribename.changed(), but it's not work

Comment: Hi Shenha, what do you mean with "not work" can i see the errors?

Comment: Also could you please upload more code into the question? Like the publish method you have

Comment: Tracker.autorun(function(){
  sites.changed();                                                                                 }) in comman.js using it I can see updated data

Answer (score 0):

Try it, it works:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
    mysqlsubscriptionname.changed();

})
```